# Using react to fetch data from google taxonomy api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react development and want to fetch data from https://www.google.com/basepages/producttype/taxonomy-with-ids.en-US.txt and post it into a tree structure.
I want to show the fetched data, not just fetch it, into a tree structure. My code is already fetching data, and I want a structure like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItKkL.png).

This is my App.js:

```js
const proxyUrl='https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
fetch( proxyUrl + 'https://yamzaidi.github.io/index.txt/gtaxFile.txt' )
.then(e=>e.text())
.then(req => {
  var s = req.split('\n');
  s.forEach(element => {
    let x = element.split('>');
    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
      console.log(' '+x[i]+' '+i);    
    }
  });
})
function App() {
  return (
    <div>this is text</div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By Stack Exchange policy, all vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tree structure you have to build on your own. I am not sure how u want to build a tree. Please explain further. Below is how to fetch correctly in React and update state.

Just tried for one example. See the URL https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ie2rt6

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState();
  const proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(proxyUrl + "https://yamzaidi.github.io/index.txt/gtaxFile.txt")
      .then(e => e.text())
      .then(req => {
        // console.log(req);
        let s = req.split('\n');
        // console.log(s.slice(1,50));
        const treeArray = s.slice(1,50);
        console.log(treeArray[6].split('>').map((x,i) => `${'\\t'.repeat(i)} ${x}`).join('\\n'))
        setText(treeArray[6].split('>').map((x,i) => `${'&nbsp;'.repeat(i*3)} ${x}`).join('<br/>'))

      });
  }, []);

  const  createMarkup = (text) => {
  return {__html: text};
}

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>

       <h2 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(text)}></h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The tree structure can be made like this

```
class Node {
  constructor(node_data_input) {
    this.data = node_data_input;
    this.children = [];
  }
}

class Tree {
  constructor() {
    this.root = new Node("Start");
  }

  insert(data) {
    data && this.insertNode(this.root, data);
  }

  insertNode(node, data) {
    if (!node.children.find((n) => n.data === data[0]))
      node.children.push(new Node(data[0]));
    else
      this.insertNode(
        node.children.find((n) => n.data === data[0]),
        data.splice(1, data.length)
      );
  }
}

const tree = new Tree();
fetch("./taxonomy.txt")
  .then((r) => r.text())
  .then((result) => {
    let data = result.split("\n").map((d) => d.split(" > "));
    data.forEach((d) => tree.insert(d));
  });
console.log(tree);
```

In this structure, any node with empty array as children is considered as leaf node.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33321905)